# Make a SQLITE query faster

Tags: sql, indexing, sqlite

I've a SQLITE table with more than 2.570.000 records and I've to select data using this query ...

```
select * from table_1 where City = 'Roma' and dist <= 0
```

... and this is the result ....

```
pgid    City    ptid     osm_id         name                                        dist
4715    Roma    1   248528643   Pronto Soccorso Ospedale "Sandro Pertini"           0
4715    Roma    9   434692525   Aurelia Hospital                                    0
4715    Roma    24  1273194519  Pronto Soccorso Ospedale Oftalmico                  0
4715    Roma    64  2318096925  Pronto Soccorso                                     0
4715    Roma    130 4839842653  Pronto Soccorso Policlinico Tor Vergata             0
4715    Roma    190 5220345821  Pronto Soccorso Ospedale Bambino Gesù               0
4715    Roma    192 5220405958  Pronto Soccorso CTO "Andrea Alesini"                0
4715    Roma    194 5220418538  Pronto Soccorso Ospedale "Cristo Re"                0
4715    Roma    197 5220461914  Pronto Soccorso Ospadale "Giovanni Battista Grassi" 0
4715    Roma    198 5220473819  Pronto Soccorso Ospedale "Madre G. Vannini"         0
4715    Roma    202 5222071850  Pronto Soccorso Policlinico "Agostino Gemelli"      0
4715    Roma    203 5222084908  Pronto Soccorso Policlinico Casilino                0
4715    Roma    206 5222104766  Pronto Soccorso Ospedale "San Camillo"              0
4715    Roma    207 5222113675  Pronto Soccorso Ospedale "San Filippo Neri"         0
4715    Roma    208 5222142783  Pronto Soccorso Ospedale "San Giovanni Calibita"    0
4715    Roma    213 5222229247  Pronto Soccorso Ospedale "Sant'Andrea"              0
4715    Roma    214 5222235383  Pronto Soccorso Ospedale "Sant'Eugenio"             0
```

It's working but the query is not so fast (sometimes more than a minute when I enter in Sqlite the first time ....), so I've to optimize it.

May I to create a index somewhere? The only field  that I could use as unique key is the osm_id field .. all the others fields are not unique

I'm quite a newbie in SQL so I need to some suggestions / example will be appreciated

Comment: Do you need to select all columns?

Comment: probably I could olny use "City", "osm_id" and "name"

Comment: And all the rows too every time?

Comment: yes in my select I've to use both the city name and the distance that could be different every time

Comment: I would definitely consider creating an index on `city` and `dist` if you are going to be querying on those often. Generally fields that you commonly use in your `FROM.. ON..` clause and your `WHERE` clause are good candidates for indexing. [Here's a good resource](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-index/) for learning about indexes in sqlite (what they are, how they work, why you want them, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query:

```
select *
from table_1
where City = 'Roma' and dist <= 0
```

You can create an index:

```
create index idx_table1_city_dist on table_1(city, dist);
```

The order of the columns in the index is important.  `city` needs to be first.

Answer (score -2):

1- Create a non clustered index on City and dist column,

2- Don't use `select *` if you really don't need all the rows, just select what you need,

3- Use stored procedures instead of executing text commands from the code,

4- Sometimes using partitions may improve performence, [see here.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177411(v=sql.105).aspx)